# Slimming down psql calls in database config creation

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql

I currently have the following calls to psql to setup my PostgreSQL database. I'd like to slim this down as each time I have to input a password for every call. I haven't had much experience with psql so am not too sure about the best way to do all of the following in a shorter, more user friendly fashion.
Thanks.

```
# Create DB
psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1 -c "CREATE DATABASE \"main\" WITH OWNER maindb;"
# PostGIS setup
psql -U postgres --dbname main -h 127.0.0.1 -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;"
# Create users table
psql -U maindb --dbname main -h 127.0.0.1 -a -f ../lib/sql/Users.sql
# Create interests table
psql -U maindb --dbname main -h 127.0.0.1 -a -f ../lib/sql/Interests.sql
# Create user-interests table
psql -U maindb --dbname main -h 127.0.0.1 -a -f ../lib/sql/UserInterests.sql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> each time I have to input a password for every call

Solve this part by using a `.pgpass` file. Then you can make as many calls to `psql` as you want.